# Trust a self signed certificate using Httpclient

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

I'm attempting to make a web request that's failing because of a self signed certificate :

```
Client = new HttpClient(); 
HttpResponseMessage Response = await Client.GetAsync(Uri)//defined elsewhere
```

This throws a trust failure exception.

I tried again using `httpclienthandler` as suggested here [Allowing Untrusted SSL Certificates with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient):

```
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

 handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
 (
   HttpRequestMessage message, 
   X509Certificate2 cert, 
   X509Chain chain, 
   SslPolicyErrors errors
  ) =>{return true; };//remove if this makes it to production 

  Client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

This blows up throwing a system not implemented exception.

Are there any other ways to trust a self signed cert? I've even installed the certificate on the machine making the request but no luck.

Comment: What platform is this running on?

Comment: This is targeting IOS using xamarin/c#

Comment: What `HttpClientImplementation` are you using?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, I'm just getting started with something that's not PHP here, I'm using `System.net.Http` installed from the nugent package manager of Visual Studios

Comment: HttpClient Implementation is marked as `managed (default)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have seen so many question regarding this I figured I write up as a  complete answer and example as I can.

Note: Using `WKWebView` with self-sign certs, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400391/xamarin-wkwebview-accepting-self-signed-certificates/47402915#47402915)

### HttpClient Implementation

Note: Using [badssl.com](https://badssl.com) in this example

#### Managed (Default)

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> 
>   System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.) ---> 
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> 
>   Mono.Security.Interface.Tl

The original Mono `Managed` provider is getting *really* long in the tooth and only supports TLS1.0, in terms of security & performance I would move to using the NSUrlSession implementation.

#### CFNetwork (iOS 6+)

Note: As this iOS version is fairly old now and I personally do not target it anymore, so I leave this blank... (unless someone really needs me to lookup my notes for it ;-)

#### NSUrlSession (iOS 7+)

Xamarin provides a `HttpMessageHandler` subclass (`NSUrlSessionHandler`) that is based upon iOS' `NSUrlSession`.

Using it by itself against a self-signed cert will result in:

> System.Net.WebException: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. --->
>   Foundation.NSErrorException: 
>   Exception of type 'Foundation.NSErrorException' was thrown.

The problem is that a self-sign cert is considered insecure and non-trusted by iOS, thus you have to apply an ATS exception to your app so iOS knows that your app is untrusted in the `Info.plist`.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>self-signed.badssl.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now that iOS knows that your app is making untrusted calls, a `HttpClient` request will now result in this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be‚ self-signed.badssl.com‚ which could put your confidential information at risk. ---> 
>   Foundation.NSErrorException: Exception of type 'Foundation.NSErrorException' was thrown.

This error is due to the fact that even though the ATS exception has been allow, the **default** `NSUrlSession` provided by iOS will apply its standard  `NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge` to the certificate and fail since a self-signed cert can never be truly authenticated (even via client pinning) since it does not include a root certificate authority (CA) in its chain that is trusted by iOS.

Thus you need to intercept and bypass the certificate security checking provided by iOS (Yes, a big security alert, flashing red lights, etc...)

*But*, you can do this via creating a `NSUrlSessionDataDelegate` subclass that does the bypass.

```
public class SelfSignedSessionDataDelegate : NSUrlSessionDataDelegate, INSUrlSessionDelegate
{
    const string host = "self-signed.badssl.com";
    public override void DidReceiveChallenge(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
    {
        switch (challenge.ProtectionSpace.Host)
        {
            case host:
                using (var cred = NSUrlCredential.FromTrust(challenge.ProtectionSpace.ServerSecTrust))
                {
                    completionHandler.Invoke(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, cred);
                }
                break;
            default:
                completionHandler.Invoke(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.PerformDefaultHandling, null);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to apply that `NSUrlSessionDataDelegate` to a `NSUrlSession` and use that new session in the creation of your `NSUrlSessionHandler` that will be provided in the constructor of the `HttpClient`.

```
var url = "https://self-signed.badssl.com";
using (var selfSignedDelegate = new SelfSignedSessionDataDelegate())
using (var session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(NSUrlSession.SharedSession.Configuration, (INSUrlSessionDelegate)selfSignedDelegate, NSOperationQueue.MainQueue))
using (var handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler(session))
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
using (var content = response.Content)
{
    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Note:** Example only, normally you would create a single Delegate, NSUrlSession, HttpClient, NSUrlSessionHandler and re-use it for all your requests (i.e. Singleton pattern)

Your request now works:

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>self-signed.badssl.com</title>
  </head>
  <body><div id="content"><h1 style="font-size: 12vw;">
    self-signed.<br>badssl.com
    </h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** The option to supply your own custom `NSUrlSession` to Xamarin's  `NSUrlSessionHandler` is really **new** (Nov. 2017) and not currently in a release build (alpha, beta or stable), but of course, source is available at:

- [xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/2b1e34caa4fba0086ef863278caff4ae5a1f1fa2/src/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs)

#### Using `NSUrlSession` instead of `HttpClient`:

You can also directly use a `NSUrlSession` instead of `HttpClient` against a self-signed cert.

```
var url = "https://self-signed.badssl.com";
using (var selfSignedDelegate = new SelfSignedSessionDataDelegate())
using (var session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(NSUrlSession.SharedSession.Configuration, (INSUrlSessionDelegate)selfSignedDelegate, NSOperationQueue.MainQueue))
{
    var request = await session.CreateDataTaskAsync(new NSUrl(url));
    var cSharpString = NSString.FromData(request.Data, NSStringEncoding.UTF8).ToString(); 
    Console.WriteLine(cSharpString);
}
```

**Note:** Example only, normally you would create a single Delegate and NSUrlSession and re-use it for all your requests, i.e. Singleton pattern

#### Real Solution? Use Free Secure Certificates:

IHMO, avoid self-signed certs all together, even in a development environment and use one of the free certificate services and avoid all the headaches of applying ATS exceptions, custom code to intercept/bypass iOS security, etc... and make your app web services actually secure.

I personally use Let’s Encrypt:

- https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: Thank you or this in depth write up! This has been very beneficial for me!

Comment: Thanks for the write up! Literally the only thing I can manage to find on this. But, I have some issues: The source being available for this is awesome, but how are we supposed to use it in an actual application? For us, we're not trying to bypass a self-signed cert, but rather do certificate pinning.

Comment: @ThomasF. Are you trying to use a `WKWebView` via a client pinned cert?

Comment: Nah, and actually I'm not sure if this stuff applies to `Xamarin.Forms` *(I just noticed this was tagged Xamarin.iOS not Forms)*. I'm trying to implement a web API that's being called via `HttpClient` but using `NSUrlSessionHandler` and pin the API certificate.This example works great up to the point where I can't actually make `NSUrlSessionHandler` use the session and custom `NSUrlSessionDataDelegate DidReceiveChallenge` implementation :/

Comment: @ThomasF. Does it apply to Forms, yes, as Forms is *just* the UI, not the actual platform app. You can apply the `NSUrlSessionHandler` via the build settings within your `Xamarin.iOS` project and thus all `HttpClient` instances will have the `NSUrlSessionHandler` applied "auto-magically".  You can then pin against it via the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, take a look at : https://thomasbandt.com/certificate-and-public-key-pinning-with-xamarin

Comment: Ah ok, see I thought that `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` was only managed, so it wouldn't be used if you picked the native handler. Thanks, that clears some things up!

Comment: @ThomasF. The `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` will work in this case since you are not using self-signed certs, if you run into problems post a new question. Happy Coding 

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, there seems to be a new property `NSUrlSessionHandler.TrustOverrideForUrl` that may be more convenient than creating a delegate, but achieves the same goal.

Comment: Your 'real solution' doesn't account for anyone calling HTTPS servers on their local network. For example, I'm trying to call a JSON-RPC service on the OpenWrt box that routes my Internet connection, and LE are great but I can't ask them to validate a cert on an HTTPS server that isn't open to the Internet (as far as I'm aware.) 
I don't want any old device connected to my network (e.g. Google Chromecast) to be able to see the traffic in cleartext. So... the real solution in this case IS to use a self-signed certificate.

Comment: I get an error assigning the handler in MAUI : cannot convert from 'Foundation.NSUrlSession' to 'Foundation.NSUrlSessionConfiguration', any idea ?

Comment: Here an example with `NSUrlSessionHandler.TrustOverrideForUrl` delegate `var handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler();
handler.TrustOverrideForUrl = (session, url, trust) => { return url switch { "{your_url_here}" => true, _ => false };};`